# E-mail attachment sent via Zend_Mail not forwardable

Tags: php, zend-framework, email-attachments

I'm maintaining an app developed in Zend 1.12, Php 5.6 and allowing users to auto send e-mails with a report in attachment.

The issue is : when a recipient try to forward the e-mail, the report in attachment is not forwarded.

I wonder if I have to add/remove a header somewhere to make the attachment forwardable ?

Comment: Do you send your emails as HTML?

Comment: yes, the body of the sent emails is in html

Comment: For your information, I found an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497672/multipart-messages-including-multiple-attachments-attachment-and-inline-wi?rq=1